# How to structure a Django website

Tags: django

After creating reusable Django apps do one make an app that glue them together to create a website?  Also is it correct to make each menu item and section an app itself in Django?  The source code of https://www.djangoproject.com/ is probably the best example of how to correctly structure Django websites if it is available.

Comment: Think what you're trying to achieve with your architecture, if you're working on a "Hello Kitty" page alone, there probably not much sense in creating arbitrary non-reusable apps. In one of my recent Django projects, we have, among others, these apps: payment (paying for services, identifying people via payments), register (all the ways a user can create and manage their account), common (utility stuff), location (geo math, dealing with Google Maps API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you organise your project is up to you and mostly depends on the project's specific needs, but yes using a "main" app to glue the pieces together is a common and working pattern. Also you don't have to try and make your project's apps reusable - start with just what your project requires and if you find out some parts solve recurring problems it will be time to factor them out as more generic apps.

Wrt/ your menus they have to match the site features not it's implementation so the "one app one menu" thing very seldom makes sense. And since it's a "glue" part it really belongs to the project's main app (even if it usually delegates parts of the job to other apps).